# Best Technology for a medical 3D Planning Software

Tags: c++, python, image-processing, 3d, image-manipulation

I am looking to build a new Interactive 3D planning software similar to this one http://www.materialise.com/materialise/view/en/131410-SimPlant.html

I was looking for some expert advise about the best technologies to use to build the different components of the software (ie: UI, Image processing, visualization, 3D, etc.. )

The software need to be able to process the images very quickly and in the same time I need to be able to deliver the software to the market fast, so the technologies used should  allow for both rapid application development, and high performance. Any advise would be appreciated

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984962/best-programming-language-for-medical-image-processing/985041#985041 My answer is still pretty much the same.

Answer (score 2):

The Python Imaging Library, [PIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library), is a good compromise between speed-to-market and good performance (and you can always use [scipy](https://scipy.org/) and its core part, [numpy](https://numpy.org/), to enrich it for more advanced image-processing needs, if you pick Python as your pivot language!-). Similarly, visualization (including 3D) are excellently covered in third-party Python extensions -- check out [EPD](https://web.archive.org/web/20130403011619/http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php), the Enthought Python Distribution, for a good idea of what libraries might best help you in such tasks (you can always build your own versions if you don't want to partner with Enthought for commercial distribution... but it might be worth checking them out, as they have excellent commercial contacts as well as tech skills;-).

When and if you want to dip down into C++ for some specific component, [Boost.Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/python/doc/index.html), [SIP](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/intro), or [Cython](https://cython.org/) will make it child's play to integrate the component into your Python mainstream. For UI &c, [PyQt](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) is great...

In other words, while I'm obviously biased, in your shoes I'd unhesitatingly go for Python as the "core" and investigate the various options I've mentioned for visualization, UI, etc, etc. One caveat: for quick time-to-market, stick with Python 2.6: the newest 3.1, while great in many respects, is likely to still miss compatible versions of many third party extensions that will make your life way easier and sweeter with Python 2.6!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at VTK (vtk.org) for an general purpose visualization toolkit and the ITK (itk.org) 
which is an image analysis toolkit built on top of vtk. Both are BSD licensed.

Comment: do you think the ITK-SNAP will be more useful http://www.itksnap.org/

Comment: Not to the questioner.  ITK-SNAP is an application by itself, not a library or framework which one builds applications on.

Answer (score 0):

ITK is not built on top of VTK, although they are related.  One can easily process data with ITK and then switch to a VTK pipeline for the visualization and interaction functionality.

We have built fairly large and complex medical image processing and visualization applications (experimental, surgical planning) in Python using a combination of VTK, ITK and wxPython.  The licensing of all these components is such that you can use them in commercial applications.